# None of the event occurs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, event-handling

This is my code.I am trying to make the ball move using arrow keys.
As i run the above program **ball is not displayed** (*if i change the coordinates to like 0,30 ball is displayed)*
                           **and event is not fired ,ball neither moves nor jumps**

`What is the problem`?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ControlledBall extends JPanel{

int diameter = 30;
int height = 30;
int x_Pos = 0;
int y_Pos;

ControlledBall() {
  JFrame fr = new JFrame("Controlled Ball");
  this.setBackground(Color.black);
  fr.add(this);
  fr.setVisible(true);
  fr.setSize(600,400);
  y_Pos = this.getHeight() - diameter ;
  register();  
  repaint();
}

public void register() {
  this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
       if( ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_RIGHT ) {
           increment();
       }
   else  if( ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_LEFT ) {
           decrement();
       }
       else if( ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_UP) {
           jump();
       }
    }
 });
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);
 g.setColor( Color.blue );
 g.fillOval( x_Pos , y_Pos , diameter , height );
 System.out.println("testing...");
}  

public void increment() {
 x_Pos++;
  if( x_Pos > (this.getWidth() - diameter) ) {
    x_Pos = this.getWidth() - diameter;
  }
 repaint();
}

public void decrement() {
 x_Pos--;
  if( x_Pos <= 0) {
    x_Pos = 0;
  }
 repaint();
}

public void jump() {
 y_Pos++;
  if( y_Pos <=0 ) {
   y_Pos = 0;
 }
repaint();
}

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    new ControlledBall();
  }
}
```

Comment: Takes you back to the days at the university, doesn't it. I think I almost remember this assignment. Good luck with it!

Comment: down voter may explain the reason please

Comment: Is the event really not fired?

Comment: @ finsterr It doesn't seem so

Comment: Does the JPanel capturing keyboard events? I would try a) adding System.out.println to the KeyAdapter in order to check if the events are being processed and b) if they are not, add the listener to the JFrame

Comment: I guess the KeyListener event is not intercepted by the correct Swing component. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780910/jpanel-keylistener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ControlledBall extends JPanel{

int diameter = 30;
int height = 30;
int x_Pos = 0;
int y_Pos;

ControlledBall() {
  JFrame fr = new JFrame("Controlled Ball");
  fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setBackground(Color.red);    
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
  fr.add(this);
  fr.setVisible(true);
  // important!
  fr.pack();
  //fr.setSize(600,400);
  y_Pos = this.getHeight()/2;
  register();
  repaint();
}

public void register() {
    // very important!
    setFocusable(true);
  this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
       if( ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_RIGHT ) {
           increment();
       }
   else  if( ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_LEFT ) {
           decrement();
       }
       else if( ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_UP) {
           jump();
       }
    }
 });
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);
 g.setColor( Color.orange );
 g.fillOval( x_Pos , y_Pos , diameter , height );
}

public void increment() {
 x_Pos++;
  if( x_Pos > (this.getWidth() - diameter) ) {
    x_Pos = this.getWidth() - diameter;
  }
 repaint();
}

public void decrement() {
 x_Pos--;
  if( x_Pos <= 0) {
    x_Pos = 0;
  }
 repaint();
}

public void jump() {
 y_Pos++;
  if( y_Pos <=0 ) {
   y_Pos = 0;
 }
repaint();
}

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    new ControlledBall();
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference b/w `pack` and `setSize` methods ?

Comment: what does `setFocusable(true)` do ?

Comment: `pack()` causes the GUI to be laid out & assume it's preferred size.  Calling `setPreferredSize()` should only be done on be done on custom components, `setSize()` should never be called, and will often be ignored (for components that are not top level containers).

Comment: See [Component.setFocusable(boolean)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 2):

Please replace the code with the following code and you will get the real picture that the KeyEvent are been consumed by the main JFrame.

To make sure you get all those events, you don't have to register on components, but rahter by using a [KeyboardFocusManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html), which will receive key events wherevere they occur.

```
ControlledBall() {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Controlled Ball");
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.white ) );
        fr.add(this);
        fr.setSize(600,400);
        y_Pos = this.getHeight() - diameter ;
        register();  
        fr.setVisible(true);
        repaint();
        fr.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() 
        {   
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("I am here.....");
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this construtor and modify your `jump, increment` and `decrement` logic accordingly !!!!
You need to add listener to the frame and not to the panel.

`int x_Pos = 30;`
`int y_Pos = 15;`

```
ControlledBall() {
    JFrame fr = new JFrame("Controlled Ball");
    this.setBackground(Color.black);
    fr.add(this);
    fr.setVisible(true);
    fr.setSize(600, 400);
    fr.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_RIGHT) {
                System.out.println("Right Key");
                increment();
            } else if (ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_LEFT) {
                System.out.println("Left Key");
                decrement();
            } else if (ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_UP) {
                System.out.println("Up Key");
                jump();
            }
        }
    });
    y_Pos = this.getHeight() - diameter;
    //register();
    repaint();
}
```