# Event listener doesn't work in one class but does in another

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, keyboard-events

I have this Class, which I made a `KeyboardEvent` class that extends `KeyAdapter` when I add `addKeyListener` to this class like so, and press a key it (for now) does `System.out.println("Here");` but nothing prints out, it doesn't do any thing (an there are no errors).

```
public class Ship extends GameObject{ // GameObject Extends JPanel
    public Ship(Sprite sprite, ImageObserver o){
        super(sprite, o);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyboardEvent());
    }
}
```

But when I do this, it works, aka it prints out "Here":

```
public class Game extends JFrame{
    public void start(int width, int height){
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyboardEvent());
    }
}
```

in some other class I run this:

```
package test;

import JGame.Game.Game;
import JGame.Room.Room;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import test.Rooms.Room1;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game("Test Game");
        game.start(800, 600);

        Room room1 = new Room1(); // This class initiates Ship() it extends Room Which extends JPanel
        game.setRoom(room1);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, use Key Bindings. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780910/jpanel-keylistener