# JPanel inside a JPanel don't listen to KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, key-bindings

at the moment i am making a level editor in Java.
The level is in a JPanel. Inside this JPanel i put the game elements(Hero, enemy, tree, wall..)For every element i use the class.GameElement.

```
public class GameElement extends JPanel
 {
protected int posX, posY;
private Color color;


public GameElement(int x, int y, Color color)
{
    this.posX = x;
    this.posY = y;
    this.color = color;

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
}

}
```

The class GameElement is also a JPanel. I want the game element hero moveable by using the KeyListener.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Hero extends Entity implements KeyListener
{
public Hero(int x, int y, Color color)
{
    super(x, y, color);


    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k)
{
    if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        this.move(0, -1);
    }
    else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        this.move(0, 1);
    }
    else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        this.move(-1, 0);
    }
    else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        this.move(1, 0);
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k)
{

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k)
{

}
}
```

When i start the Level editor. The hero display succesfull on my screen but it doesn't move when i press the key button. Is it because i'm not focussing on the right JPanel?

Comment: For a game, you probably need to register a global key listener, to make sure you always get the key event. There are a few questions on SO for that, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780910/jpanel-keylistener

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10603588/1360074 "KeyListener isn‘t designated for listening of keyboard events for Swing JComponents, use KeyBindings instead"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class extending KeyListener not responding to key presses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221458/class-extending-keylistener-not-responding-to-key-presses)

Answer (score 6):

It is not that you are focusing on the wrong `JPanel` but rather that `JPanel` is not focusable and so cannot interact with `KeyEvents`. This is why in Swing it is better to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which allow you to map an Action to a KeyStroke even when a component doesn't have focus.

[example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

Answer (score 1):

You may add an [AWTEventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AWTEventListener.html) to the default [Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) to listen for all key events, not depending on which element has the focus (just the application must have the focus):

```
    AWTEventListener theListener = new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event);
        }
    };
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    toolkit.addAWTEventListener(theListener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

**Edit**
`AWTEvents` are kind of low-level events, prefer to use [ActionMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ActionMap.html)/[InputMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html) (or just [registerKeyboardAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#registerKeyboardAction%28java.awt.event.ActionListener,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.KeyStroke,%20int%29) )